# How would one instantiate a class given a ProgID alone in C++?

Tags: c++, com

Say I have a progid Prog.Class. In something like powershell, this is enough to do things

```
$obj = New-Object -COM "Prog.Class"
$obj.method();
```

In C++ though, I need to know the supported interfaces

```
CoCreateInstance(CLSIDFromProgID(...),...,IID_SomeInterface,...)
```

How do I get away with this in C++ knowing only the progid and not the interface IDs? Is there a way to get the possible interface IDs? Can I just do something like CoCallMethodOnClass(...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Powershell uses IID_IDispatch to obtain an [IDispatch*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221608%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  The interface that supports late binding, many COM servers implement it.

C++ does not support late binding in its language syntax, that does make it a much more painful affair.  You'll have to call IDispatch::GetIDsOfNames() to translate the member name "method" to a DispId, IDispatch::Invoke() to call it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no way to get the list of supported IIDs, but it wouldn't be useful to know an IID if you don't have the C++ type information of the associated interface (what are you gonna do with the IID alone?).

However, it's still possible to use a COM object without knowing about its interfaces, by using the IDispatch interface. IDispatch contains methods for invoking methods on the object based on method names or DISPIDs. This is known as late binding, as opposed to early binding where you invoke methods based on compile-time information about interfaces.

Of course, in C++ it's preferable to use early binding, just because using IDispatch requires a lot of boilerplate code that C++ doesn't automate. Late binding is mostly intended for interoperability with languages that are either dynamically-typed or can benefit in other ways from late binding, such as the "old" VB or Powershell.